# Deriving the CDF of student $t$-distribution

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, t-distribution

I am trying to derive the cumulative density function(cdf) of $t$-distribution, define as in

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

I derive it by the following steps:

$F(x)=\int_{-\infty }^{x}\frac{\Gamma (\frac{v+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi v}\Gamma (\frac{v}{2})}(1+\frac{t^2}{v})^{-(\frac{v+1}{2})}dt$

Substituting

$\frac{1}{z}=1+\frac{t^2}{v}$

$dt=-\frac{v}{2z^{2}\sqrt{v(\frac{1}{z}-1)}}dz$,

we get:

$F(x)=-\frac{\Gamma (\frac{v+1}{2})}{2\sqrt{\pi v}\Gamma (\frac{v}{2})}\int_{0}^{\frac{v}{v+x^2}}(\frac{1}{z})^{-(\frac{v+1}{2})}\frac{v}{z^{2}\sqrt{v(\frac{1}{z}-1)}}dz$

By simplifying we get:

$F(x)=-\frac{\Gamma (\frac{v+1}{2})}{2\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma (\frac{v}{2})}\int_{0}^{\frac{v}{v+x^2}}z^{(\frac{v}{2})-1}(1-z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}dz$

But further I cannot understand how to simplify it to derive the final cdf which is given by:

$\frac{1}{2}+x\Gamma (\frac{v+1}{2})\frac{2F1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^2}{v})}{\sqrt{\pi v}\Gamma (\frac{v}{2})}$

Can somebody help me in deriving this?

Best Regards.

Comment: First, the change of variables is not one-to-one, so you need to correct for this. Second, the final integral is a Beta cdf integral.

Comment: I believe the hypergeometric function will drop right out when you expand the integrand using the Binomial Theorem.  It converges absolutely in the interval of integration and so can be integrated term by term.  The resulting power series is hypergeometric.  This assumes, though, that you fix the typographical errors in your expression for $F$!  (In particular, "$z$" seems to have turned into "$t$" at some point.)